# QT QuaZip open() fail -1000

Tags: android, c++, qt, zip, quazip

I am trying to uncompress a Zip file. Using the latest Qt 5.15 on an Android device.

```
QFile downloadedZipFile(VALID_ZIP_LOCATION);
QuaZip zip(&downloadedZipFile);
if (!zip.open(QuaZip::mdUnzip)) {
    qDebug() << "error" << zip.getZipError();
}
```

If my file is above 2GB it am getting an error -1000.
Files below 2GB are working as expected.

I tried

```
zip.setZip64Enabled(true);
```

before opening the file without success.
I also tried to use the constructor

```
QuaZip zip(VALID_ZIP_LOCATION)
```

Upon accessing the zip later I also get the following error:

> QuaZip::goToFirstFile(): ZIP is not open in mdUnzip mode

which makes sense, as it couldn't open the file in the first place.

Any help is appreciated, as I am struggling with this Problem for a few days already.

Comment: Are you sure your "above 2GB" zip file not compressed with deflate64? Quazip uses zlib and zlib doesn't support deflate64 compression.
I was looking for "perfect" zip extraction library myself and found that none of C libraries actually support deflate64. The only solution currently exists its to use 7-zip library for decompression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is an unresolved QT-Bug. Where QFile::seek cannot exceed a limit above a 32Bit Integer.
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-84033

After identifying the problem I could resolve this issue by implementing native code for unzipping files in java for android.
Since iPhones are only running on 64Bit systems the native implementation did not need to be ported to ObjC.

Comment: Maybe you could give more information about how you solved the issue "*by implementing native code for unzipping files in java for android.*" to help others with the same problem in the future.

Comment: Also: The question is tagged as C++. Is going to Java the only solution?

Comment: Instead of using QuaZip on Android devices I implemented the unzipping logic in Java.
Java Unzipping is thoroughly documented and a quick GoogleSearch should get you going.
Using Java seems to be the only solution